CSS content aligns incorrectly when only one line of text
I've got the below code. Everything is working pretty great except when the browser is wide enough that the text is only one line, the "posts" get misaligned.
Example:

I've messed with all the CSS I can think of and I can't get it to align correctly. Thanks in advance for your help!
Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/BHolm/n68r5xst/167/


/*Feed*/
 
.feed-row {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.feed-mt .post-submitted-info {  
  font-weight: 700; 
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 1; 
  position: relative; 
   
}

.post-submitted-info { 
  column-width: 55px; 
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.submitted-date { 
  border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2; 
}

.submitted-date { 
  margin-top: 12px; 
}

.post-submitted-info .year { 
  padding-bottom: 8px 
}

.post-submitted-info .month, .post-submitted-info .year {  
  font-size: 14px; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.feed-mt .post-submitted-info .day { 
  font-size: 29px; 
  font-weight: 900; 
  padding-bottom: 2px; 
}

.feed-main-content {
  padding-left: 75px;
  margin-top: -75px;
}

.field-item{  
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #acacac;
  
}

.feed-main-content .header {
    
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Load Handlebars.js from Unpkg. -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/handlebars@4.5.0/dist/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load jQuery and Sheetrock from Unpkg -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sheetrock@1.2.0/dist/sheetrock.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="hf">
    <script id="hf-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

<!-- Post Date Section -->
      <div class="row feed-row feed-mt">
        <div class="post-submitted-info">
            <div class="submitted-date">
            <div class="month">{{cells.Month}}</div>
            <div class="day">{{cells.Day}}</div>
            <div class="year">{{cells.Year}}</div>         
            </div>
        </div>
        
<!-- Post Content Section -->
        <div class="feed-main-content">
            <div class="header">
            <h2>{{cells.Header}}</h2>
          </div>
            <div class="field-item">
            <p>{{cells.Content}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
  </div>
</body>




Once we have a simple HTML/CSS situation to work with I'll have another look. My usual approach with something like this is to back out to a simple grid and start fresh. You seem to have much more CSS than you need, and probably extra markup, too. You're also very far away from a Bootstrap layout, which I'd think would get you 95% of the way there without any CSS.

You're almost certainly right about having too much CSS. I actually took the CSS from an existing site that had the look I wanted and trimmed, trimmed, trimmed. You should've seen how much was there initially.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/

The problem was the top margin that you used, you used it negatively
/*Feed*/
.feed-mt{
  display:flex;
  gap:10px
}
 
.feed-row {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.feed-mt .post-submitted-info {  
  font-weight: 700; 
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 1; 
  position: relative; 
   
}

.post-submitted-info { 
  column-width: 55px; 
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.submitted-date { 
  border-right: 1px solid #c2c2c2; 
}

.submitted-date { 
  margin-top: 12px; 
  width:60px;
}

.post-submitted-info .year { 
  padding-bottom: 8px 
}

.post-submitted-info .month, .post-submitted-info .year {  
  font-size: 14px; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.feed-mt .post-submitted-info .day { 
  font-size: 29px; 
  font-weight: 900; 
  padding-bottom: 2px; 
}

.feed-main-content {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:start;
  width:calc(100% - 100px);
}

.field-item{  
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #acacac;
}

.feed-main-content .header {
    
}

